# Application of PIE

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A_1, . . . , A_m$ be sets such that $|A_i| = n$ and $A_i \bigcap A_j$ = ∅ for $i \ne j$.
Find the number of sequences of elements from $\bigcup A_i$ which have the
following properties: (1) Every element from $\bigcup A_i$ appears exactly once
in the sequence and (2) For every $i = 1, . . . m$, the elements of $A_i$ are
not consecutive.

Comment: What does consecutive mean here?

Comment: two elements from the set $A_i$ are placed at k and k+1 position in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The case where $n=2$ is indeed solvable with PIE.

Let $B_j$ be the sequences such that the two elements of $A_j$ are consecutive.

> For each $k=1,\ldots,m$:$$\begin{align}|\text{Any intersection of $k$ of the $B$'s}|&=\left|B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_k\right|\\&=(2m-k)!\times 2^k\end{align}$$
>
> > because we can consider those $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ as blocks of 2 first and permute the blocks, and then multiply by 2 for each pair which can be reordered.

$$\left|\bigcup_j B_j\right|=\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k-1}{m\choose k}\left|B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_k\right|$$

$$\text{Ans}=(2m)!-\left|\bigcup_j B_j\right|=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k{m\choose k} 2^k(2m-k)!$$

On the linked question there is a formula for the case $m=3$ (that formula must be multiplied by $n!^3$. For verification, both formulae give $240$ when $n=2$ and $m=3$. But I think we have not found a general formula for this when $n,m$ are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

*Possible first step:*

First choose the number of ways to set which indices are allocated to each set.

Then multiply by ${n!}^m$ to permute the elements of each set.

Comment: I guess choosing is the hardest part, as after we have the indices they can be permuted in $n!^m$ ways.

Comment: You're right, it is not so easy. Give me some time to think about it.

Comment: Just curious, where did you get this problem? Do you know if there's a simple answer in the form of a summation/product, etc.?

Comment: Nope this is the unfortunate part, answer was not given. This was listed as one of the possible questions that could show up in the exam. Fortunately it didn't. Even i am curious about the actual source :D.

Comment: I'm now thinking along the lines of the function $f(n,m,k)$ which is the number of ways to arrange the $m$ groups of $n$ elements so that $k$ groups satisfy the property. Maybe a recurrence can be obtained from this, using PIE.

Comment: Maybe ask a simpler question first, like how many ways are there to arrange 3 a's, 3 b's and 3 c's so that no two identical letters are adjacent... Perhaps there will be answers which can be extended? I believe this simple case is doable by PIE by analysing the resulting cases.

Comment: OK, I've posted a follow up question (see Linked on the right). Someone posted a wrong answer like I did for your question at first, I gave him a counterexample, and then he deleted his answer. I thought of deleting this post (so that it will be back to the "unanswered" status), but I can't do so without deleting the comments as well, so I'm not going to, unless you want.

Comment: no no , please keep this post. no need to delete.